# Nest.js webservice SELECT from Postgres DB using Knex.js query builder string encoding issue

Tags: postgresql

My eyes are damn near bleeding at this point, I have a base64 encoded working string (word document that parse correctly on the frontend) but when I do a call to the database the string that comes back is using some character encoding that I can't figure out how to fix. The knex field is called `binary` looking in the database field it' a `bytea` type

Can anyone point me as to why it's not simply retuning thr base64 string and how I can make it do so? Here's the beginning of the example incorrect string: `\\x554573444242514143416749414d71516d3159414141414141414141414141414141415141414141643239795a43396f5a57466b5a5849784c6e6874624f31583232376a4f417a3967763048772b2b746b2f5179726446304d4a31654d454378434e4c4f38304b52365668625752496f78576e363955764a6c3178365762637a6d4e6d487a554d73696551685252375238746e6e78314a4746614156576f336a346634676a6b42786e516b314838666637362f3354754c494f7159794a725743636277434733382b2f2b4e736d52595a526d537362467279635677345a39496b736279416b746c39625543524d4e6`

Thanks!

Comment: then the databse field had to be text and not bytea, as it was converted

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/using-postgresql-8-4-how-to-convert-bytea-to-text-value-in-postgres